# Insert line to markdown table from Python in ascending order

Tags: python, file, markdown

I have Markdown file with table like this:

| # | ... |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 5 |  |
| 7 |  |
| 8 |  |

I want to insert table row in ascending order by `#`. For example, 3 will be inserted at between 1 and 5. Maybe you know, how can I easily do this with some library?

I used default Python methods and library `fileinput`.

Answer (score 0):

With `pandas` that should be easy, just add the row you want, sort the DataFrame, then output the new table to Markdown, dont forget to replace `your_file.md` with the path to your actual markdown file

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

with open("your_file.md", "r") as f:
    table = f.read()

data = StringIO(table)
df = pd.read_table(data, sep="\t")

df = df.append({"#": 3}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.sort_values(by="#")

with open("your_file.md", "w") as f:
    f.write(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```